# rewriteRule or redirect of url in htaccess

Tags: redirect

I'm trying to redirect or rewrite a specific page. In my .htaccess I've tried both of these lines but neither worked. The press-releases-news/?lang=en page exists on my site but not /press-releases-news/?lang=fi, so I'm trying to avoid the 404 that results. Appreciate some pointers here.

```
Redirect 301 /press-releases-news/?lang=fi/ /press-releases-news/?lang=en
RewriteRule    /press-releases-news/?lang=fi/  /press-releases-news
```

Placed directly after RewriteEngine On

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
Redirect 301 /press-releases-news/?lang=fi/ /press-releases-news/?lang=en
RewriteRule    /press-releases-news/?lang=fi/  /press-releases-news
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.aspx?$ handleRedirect.php [L,NC] 
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} lang=fi
RewriteRule ^press-releases-news http://yourdomain.com/press-releases-news [R=301]
```

Comment: The `^` indicates the start of the uri from the present folder. So (just to clarify), your /press-releases-news/ folder is just one level down from the root, right?

Comment: It's a wordpress site so the template file (archive.php) that this page uses is a few levels down.

Comment: When you add

`RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} lang=fi
RewriteRule ^press-releases-news http://yourdomain.com/press-releases-news [R=301]`

to your `.htaccess`, where does the browser redirect to, when you try to point it at `/press-releases-news?lang=fi` ? (Or, if it doesn't redirect at all, what non-existent URI are you left looking at?)